# Update value if two columns are same

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
a <- c("A1","A1","A2","A2")
b <- c("B1","B1","B2","B2")
val <- c(10,20,30,40)

df <- data.frame(a,b,val)
```

I want to replace the the values in 'val' when the a = b and 'val' should have the value of the initial row

[image]

Comment: Is the image you provided your expected output? If so, how? None of a and b are equal in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(a,b) %>%
  mutate(val = first(val))

  a     b       val
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 A1    B1       10
2 A1    B1       10
3 A2    B2       30
4 A2    B2       30
```